# Docker images vanishing during build; image not found (Docker resource settings or K8s garbage collection?)

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kernel, docker-image

I am running a kubernetes cluster which is using docker's runtime - It is running on the same system where users are building docker images separate to the cluster. My hunch is that kubernetes is removing these newly built images to free up resources.

**Where I've encountered this issue**

I'm building multiple images back to back that depend on each other using a bash script that kicks off docker builds in sequence.

After successfully building "base-image", and moving on to the next dependent image, I encounter an error as if the previously built image no longer exists.

`manifest for localhost:5000/base-image:latest not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown`

The registry and docker daemon are correctly configured so I don't think it is related to that. I have run the script previously when the kubernetes cluster wasn't up (and again after taking it down) and was able to successfully build all images in the stack.

I'm trying to figure out what might be causing kubernetes to remove images as they are being built.

From what I could find in system message logs `var/log/messages`:

```
Feb 17 16:36:16 iI containerd: time="2021-02-17T16:36:16.786891431-05:00" level=info msg="shim disconnected" id=a711115b49c48e724eb26beb864e591d39c67d7451df6b9d3f7b64a8295dcdc0
Feb 17 16:36:16 iI dockerd: time="2021-02-17T16:36:16.786712381-05:00" level=info msg="ignoring event" container=a711115b49c48e724eb26beb864e591d39c67d7451df6b9d3f7b64a8295dcdc0 module=libcontainerd namespace=moby topic=/tasks/delete type="*events.TaskDelete"
Feb 17 16:36:16 iI kernel: docker0: port 2(vetheb1f56e) entered disabled state
Feb 17 16:36:16 iI NetworkManager[38959]: <info>  [1613597776.8478] manager: (veth35fa35a): new Veth device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/256)
Feb 17 16:36:16 iI kernel: docker0: port 2(vetheb1f56e) entered disabled state
Feb 17 16:36:16 iI kernel: device vetheb1f56e left promiscuous mode
Feb 17 16:36:16 iI kernel: docker0: port 2(vetheb1f56e) entered disabled state
Feb 17 16:36:16 iI NetworkManager[38959]: <info>  [1613597776.9086] device (vetheb1f56e): released from master device docker0
Feb 17 16:36:18 iI kernel: docker0: port 2(vethe5c7147) entered blocking state
Feb 17 16:36:18 iI kernel: docker0: port 2(vethe5c7147) entered disabled state
Feb 17 16:36:18 iI kernel: device vethe5c7147 entered promiscuous mode
Feb 17 16:36:18 iI kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): vethe5c7147: link is not ready
Feb 17 16:36:18 iI kernel: docker0: port 2(vethe5c7147) entered blocking state
Feb 17 16:36:18 iI kernel: docker0: port 2(vethe5c7147) entered forwarding state
Feb 17 16:36:18 iI kernel: docker0: port 2(vethe5c7147) entered disabled state
Feb 17 16:36:18 iI NetworkManager[38959]: <info>  [1613597778.5150] manager: (vethf13a760): new Veth device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/257)
Feb 17 16:36:18 iI NetworkManager[38959]: <info>  [1613597778.5159] manager: (vethe5c7147): new Veth device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/258)
Feb 17 16:36:18 iI containerd: time="2021-02-17T16:36:18.526369134-05:00" level=info msg="starting signal loop" namespace=moby path=/run/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/moby/6c66f06f0ec2fff4d284e6c598f34dba372c1ad5a269638419ad4496244cd562 pid=272341
Feb 17 16:36:18 iI kernel: nf_conntrack: falling back to vmalloc.
Feb 17 16:36:18 iI kernel: nf_conntrack: falling back to vmalloc.
Feb 17 16:36:18 iI kernel: IPVS: Creating netns size=2048 id=34
Feb 17 16:36:18 iI kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
Feb 17 16:36:18 iI kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Feb 17 16:36:18 iI kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): vethe5c7147: link becomes ready
Feb 17 16:36:18 iI kernel: docker0: port 2(vethe5c7147) entered blocking state
Feb 17 16:36:18 iI kernel: docker0: port 2(vethe5c7147) entered forwarding state
Feb 17 16:36:18 iI NetworkManager[38959]: <info>  [1613597778.7235] device (vethe5c7147): carrier: link connected
Feb 17 16:37:26 iI dockerd: time="2021-02-17T16:37:26.714206003-05:00" level=info msg="ignoring event" container=6c66f06f0ec2fff4d284e6c598f34dba372c1ad5a269638419ad4496244cd562 module=libcontainerd namespace=moby topic=/tasks/delete type="*events.TaskDelete"
Feb 17 16:37:26 iI containerd: time="2021-02-17T16:37:26.714307895-05:00" level=info msg="shim disconnected" id=6c66f06f0ec2fff4d284e6c598f34dba372c1ad5a269638419ad4496244cd562
Feb 17 16:37:26 iI kernel: docker0: port 2(vethe5c7147) entered disabled state
Feb 17 16:37:26 iI NetworkManager[38959]: <info>  [1613597846.7747] manager: (vethf13a760): new Veth device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/259)
Feb 17 16:37:26 iI kernel: docker0: port 2(vethe5c7147) entered disabled state
Feb 17 16:37:26 iI kernel: device vethe5c7147 left promiscuous mode
Feb 17 16:37:26 iI kernel: docker0: port 2(vethe5c7147) entered disabled state
Feb 17 16:37:26 iI NetworkManager[38959]: <info>  [1613597846.8345] device (vethe5c7147): released from master device docker0
Feb 17 16:37:32 iI dockerd: time="2021-02-17T16:37:32.422000932-05:00" level=info msg="Layer sha256:9999447d31d74880dccc238c9d55b1f00bd4a81ac6367dfa3c3013efb91cf1ef cleaned up"
Feb 17 16:37:32 iI dockerd: time="2021-02-17T16:37:32.542365965-05:00" level=info msg="Layer sha256:9999447d31d74880dccc238c9d55b1f00bd4a81ac6367dfa3c3013efb91cf1ef cleaned up"
```

**Question:**

Is this related to docker resource settings not being adequate? Or do we need to adjust kubernetes garbage collection settings running separately on the machine?
Any thoughts on what to look for or where to continue investigating?

Comment: Can you share some information about your environment and your script? Did you try command from that script to create one image?

Comment: I don't think the build script is relevant beyond the context of it building images in sequence and that subsequent images that depend on the first base image error out because the base image appears to be removed)... we have used the script before to build all images successfully when the kubernetes cluster wasn't running (and again after we took the cluster down)

Comment: So, maybe I should rephrase the question to be more targeted towards kubernetes.. and our environment.. Kubernetes is using the docker runtime instead of containerd.. what I don't know and not sure what to investigate is why would kubernetes delete images as they are being built by a separate process. And if that is the case (and related to garbage collection) what do we need to configure to prevent the removal of images